# How to test whether window.print() is not overriden?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

How to test with (JavaScript and/or) FirefoxDriver whether the `window.print()` method is overridden?

It is possible to disable all print buttons on a page like with this:

```
window.print = function() { alert("Bazinga") }
```

With this a normal "Print" link like the following one is not working anymore:

```
<a onclick="window.print()">....</a>
```

I need to check whether a `window.print()` call executes the **original** print dialog.

Maybe it is possible to inject some JavaScript into the FirefoxWebdriver?

Comment: Just curious, but how do you intend to apply this?

Comment: @Neil you mean how to inject the JavaScript to this it?

Comment: No, I meant how will the answer of this question this serve you?  I have difficulty imagining the applications of this, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKF3S/) based on Luca's answer and Christoph's comment. This function will detect native print dialog even in IE6.

```
function isNativePrint() {
    var isNative = false;
    try {
        if (window.print.toString().indexOf('[native code]') > -1) isNative = true;
    } catch (e) {
        isNative = true;
    }
    return isNative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @Luca for such an elegant way to detect native function.

Answer (score 3):

Since window.print is a native function you can:

```
if( window.print.toString().indexOf('[native code]') > -1 ) {
 //native
}
```

Comment: looks good, though IE does not seem to support `toString()` on native functions. However `window.print` yielded the desired result for me.